# Has-many through with extra attribute on join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facebook_groups, through: :group_memberships
end

class FacebookGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :profiles, through: :group_memberships
end

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facebook_group
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

I have an attribute called :favorite on the GroupMembership model
I'm building an endpoint for retrieveing a profile's groups. Something like:
{groups: [name: 'groupA', created_at: somedate, favorite: true] }
How can I get this?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find all the favorited group_memberships on a specific profile. In rails, this would usually be done by defining a scope on the GroupMembership model.

```
scope :favorites, -> { where(favorite: true) }
```

Then you can retrieve them through Profile model like so. This will give you the associated group_memberships where the favorite attribute is true:

```
@profile.group_memberships.favorites
```

Also, it looks like you need to define `has_many :group_memberships` in your Profile model to finish off the association.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think I didn't explained myself clearly.
I want to retrieve a profile's groups, and I want the attribute :favorite to be included in the result. The difficulty is the fact that I put the :favorite attribute on the group_memberships model because many profiles can be member of the same group.